# Internal slave HDD not detecting. how to recover data

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a Seagate Barracuda HDD that is set as a slave. Its within warranty. 5 days ago , the cabinet fell down from desk. The computer worked normally for 5 days. Today I could not detect the slave HDD. I have data which I don't want to lose. What should I do?

How can I check how much damage has been done? How easily can data be recovered? I have heard that the cost of data recovery depends on kind of damage done.

Also I have heard Seagate offers data recovery at extra charge. Is it expensive ?

Comment: i tried to make it slave/primary in another pc but it did not show...
hardware vendor is asking $10 inspection charge !? and i want to at least understand the problem as the repair guys talks tech mumbo -jumbo to charge high...how can i diagonise the problem ?!

Comment: @Sunny - ".." or "..." shouldn't be used in place of a "?" Also, Please limit your post to one question per post and read the FAQ http://superuser.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to check is that non of the power leads and cables have come loose.

Open the box (unplugging it first and making sure you're grounded) and firstly do a visual check. If all the cables look OK make sure by trying to push them in again. However, if you're not sure about anything don't touch. You might want to do a search on the internet for pictures of the insides of computers to familiarise yourself with what to expect and to compare what you're actually seeing.

I think this should work as you said it worked OK for the last 5 days, but it's not guaranteed.

If not (as you indicate in your comment) then something more serious is wrong and you might have to get more professional help.

Was there any change in the sounds coming from the PC? If there were then that might indicate damage to the components themselves, but that's hard to diagnose over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago, my HDD had a malfunction and I couldn't access my files. I made a small research over the net and found out that there are data recovery firms in Istanbul and they analyze the HDD totally for free, and then tell you about the damage, the probability to recover the data, and the total maximum cost. If you accept the agreement, you go with it. If you don't, you just take back your HDD and don't pay for anything. I recommend you to search for one around the place you live, and leave it to professionals.